# An O(n * log(n)) algorithm for maximum st-flow in a directed planar graph (Borradaile, Klein)

Tags: algorithm, graph, ford-fulkerson, planar-graph, edmonds-karp

Could someone explain to me using an example how Borradaile-Klein's algorithm for maximum flow works?
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.6392&rep=rep1&type=pdf

There are a lot of Ford-Fulkerson's examples (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl90tNtKvxs) but I didn't find an example for Borradaile-Klein algorithm.

Thank you.

Comment: Klein and Shay Mozes have some lecture notes (http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.889/fall11/lectures/) and a book (http://www.planarity.org/) that cover this algorithm. I can answer specific questions about this algorithm (I was Klein's PhD student) but I don't have the energy to write new tutorial material about it.